# Changing Vertex Color and Coordinates From a list or vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I'm making a visualisation of an email network of a company.
Each vertex represents a person and vertex color represents their position(BOD,CEO,manager,leader).
The edges' Thickness according to weights(amount of emails they send from a person to another).
I also need to move the position of the vertex so I can show the visualisation of the clustering and also to improve angles.
Here's my adjacency matrix with weights:

```
weightedNonSym = {
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1},
   {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0}
   };
```

Here's what I have so far for the graph:

```
    edgeMappingToWeights = 
      Sort[<|Join @@ 
         MapIndexed[Rule @@ #2 -> # &, weightedNonSym/100, {2}]|>, 
       Greater];
    edgeCount = 45;
    edge45 = Keys@Take[edgeMappingToWeights, edgeCount];
    color = {{1, 0.6, 0.8}, {1, 0.6, 0.8}, {0.9, 1, 0.7}, {1, 0.7, 
    0.2}, {1, 0.7, 0.2}, {1, 0.7, 0.2}
     , {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 
    0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}
     , {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 
    0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1, 0.9}
    };     
    GraphPlot[
 Graph[edge45, 
  EdgeStyle -> Thread[edge45 -> (Thickness[#] & /@ weights)]], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[
     Framed[Style[#2 - 1, 8, Black], 
      Background -> (RGBColor[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]] &] & /@ 
         color)], #1] &)]
```

Which produces this output:
[image]

The Vertex background doesnt seem to work though. And I'm still trying to figure out how to incorporate these coordinates for the vertex:

```
xcoor = {0, 0, 1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 6, 9, 11, 7, 10, 11, 7, 4, 5, 4};
ycoor = {6, 5, 5.5, 0.5, 11, 5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 6.5, 7.5, 7.5, 11, 10, 
   10, 6, 5, 4};

colors = {RGBColor[1, 0.6, 0.8], RGBColor[1, 0.6, 0.8], 
   RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.7], RGBColor[1, 0.7, 0.2], 
   RGBColor[1, 0.7, 0.2], RGBColor[1, 0.7, 0.2]
   , RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], 
   RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], 
   RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9]
   , RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], 
   RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], 
   RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9], RGBColor[0.9, 1, 0.9]};
vertexLabel = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[Range[18] - 1, weightedNonSym /. 0 -> ∞];

GraphPlot[wag, 
  EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[Opacity[.8], Blue, 
     Thickness[PropertyValue[{wag, e}, EdgeWeight]/400]]}, 
 VertexStyle -> {v_ :> (RGBColor @@ color[[v + 1]])}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Transpose[{xcoor, ycoor}],  
 PlotTheme -> "ClassicLabeled"]
```

[image]